# Jetpack compose: Setting ImeAction does not close or change focus for the keyboard

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I'm using Jetpack compose `1.0.0-alpha07`. I made a login screen that contains two `TextField`s customized using other composables.

However, setting `ImeAction` in `keyboardOptions` does not seem to work. For instance `ImeAction.Next` does not move focus to the next TextField. I think I should do something to make it possible, but no document or article has talked even briefly about `ImeOptions`. Here's the code I have for the screen:

**Login** composable:

```kotlin
EmailEdit(onChange = { email.value = it })
PasswordEdit(onChange = { password.value = it })
```

**EmailEdit**:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun EmailEdit(onChange: (String) -> Unit) {
    val t = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    TextField(
        value = t.value,
        onValueChange = { value ->
            t.value = value
            onChange(value)
        },
        leadingIcon = { Icon(asset = Icons.Default.Email) },
        label = { Text(text = "Email") },
        maxLines = 1,
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            imeAction = ImeAction.Next, // ** Go to next **
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email
        ),
        visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None
    )
}      errorHint = "Not a valid email"
    )
}
```

**PassEdit**:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun PasswordEdit(onChange: (String) -> Unit) {
    val t = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    TextField(
        value = t.value,
        onValueChange = { value ->
            t.value = value
            onChange(value)
        },
        leadingIcon = { Icon(asset = Icons.Default.Security) },
        label = { Text(text = "Password") },
        maxLines = 1,
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            imeAction = ImeAction.Done, // ** Done. Close the keyboard **
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text
        ),
        visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation()
    )
}
```

To perform `Done` and `Next` what code should I add?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use

- **`keyboardOptions`**: software keyboard options that contains configuration such as `KeyboardType` and `ImeAction`
- **`keyboardActions`** when the input service emits an IME action, the corresponding callback is called

For `Done`:

You can use the [**`LocalSoftwareKeyboardController`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/LocalSoftwareKeyboardController) to interact with the keyboard.

```
keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
    onDone = {keyboardController?.hide()}
)
```

For `Next`:

```
keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Next),
keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
    onNext = { focusRequester.requestFocus() }
)
```

Something like:

```
val (focusRequester) = FocusRequester.createRefs()
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        text = it
    },
    label = { Text("Label") },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Next),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
        onNext = { focusRequester.requestFocus() } 
    )
)

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        text = it
    },
    modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester),
    label = { Text("Label") },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
        onDone = { keyboardController?.hide() }
    )
)
```

Comment: Weird, I'm getting exception when trying request focus in this way:
 
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: FocusRequester is not initialized. One reason for this is that you requesting focus changes during composition. Focus requesters should not be made during composition, but should be made in response to some event.`

Comment: add Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester) to solve the IllegalStateException

Comment: Strange, keyboard closes on pressing onNext in Landscape and working fine in portrait mode.

Comment: LocalSoftwareKeyboardController is still experimental, should we use it in production yet?

Comment: With Compose 1.1.1 it seems `keyboardActions` and manual focus management are not required. `KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Next)` is enough to get correct behavior.

Answer (score 29):

You can use **LocalFocusManager**.

```
val localFocusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
```

Inside parent composable of your fields.

To move focus to next field:

```
localFocusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
```

Inside onNext of KeyboardActions to move focus in specific direction such as left, right, up and down.

To clear focus:

```
localFocusManager.clearFocus()
```

Inside *onDone* of **KeyboardActions** to clear focus.

Email Field :

```
OutlinedTextField(
            value = userId,
            onValueChange = { userId = it },
            label = { Text("Email") },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            singleLine = true,
            leadingIcon = {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_account),
                    contentDescription = "ID"
                )
            },
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                focusedBorderColor = Color.Gray,
                unfocusedBorderColor = Color.LightGray,
                focusedLabelColor = Color(0xffcc0000)
            ),
            keyboardOptions =
            KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Next
            ),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onNext = {
                localFocusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
            })
        )
```

Password Field :

```
OutlinedTextField(
            value = password,
            onValueChange = { password = it },
            label = { Text("Password") },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            singleLine = true,
            leadingIcon = {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_password),
                    contentDescription = "Password"
                )
            },
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                focusedBorderColor = Color.Gray,
                unfocusedBorderColor = Color.LightGray,
                focusedLabelColor = Color(0xffcc0000)
            ),
            keyboardOptions =
            KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Done
            ),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = {
                localFocusManager.clearFocus()
            })

        )
```

Tried with version `1.0.1`

Comment: This works. but not when a field is not visible, for example behind the keyboard.

Comment: it works for me even when field is behind the keyboard

Comment: Other solutions are more work and a hit/miss. This one is working as intended.

Answer (score 15):

use the `onImeActionPerformed` parameter.

For `Done`:

```
TextField(
    onImeActionPerformed = { _, controller ->
        controller?.hideSoftwareKeyboard()
    }
)
```

For `Next`:

```
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
TextField(
    onImeActionPerformed = { _, _ ->
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
    }
)
TextField(
    modifier = Mofifier.focusRequester(focusRequester)
)
```

Here's a working example:

```
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
val email = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
TextField(
    value = email.value,
    onValueChange = { email.value = it },
    imeAction = ImeAction.Next,
   onImeActionPerformed = { _, _ -> focusRequester.requestFocus() }
)
val password = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
TextField(
    value = password.value,
    onValueChange = { password.value = it },
    imeAction = ImeAction.Done,
    onImeActionPerformed = { _, controller -> controller?.hideSoftwareKeyboard() },
    modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester)
)
```

Documentation:

- FocusRequestModifier: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/FocusRequesterModifier
- TextField: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#TextField(kotlin.String,%20kotlin.Function1,%20androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,%20androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle,%20kotlin.Function0,%20kotlin.Function0,%20kotlin.Function0,%20kotlin.Function0,%20kotlin.Boolean,%20androidx.compose.ui.text.input.VisualTransformation,%20androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions,%20kotlin.Int,%20kotlin.Function2,%20kotlin.Function1,%20androidx.compose.foundation.InteractionState,%20androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,%20androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,%20androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,%20androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,%20androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape)

Comment: What about if we have more than 2 textfields. How to focus next step by step?

Comment: I think for each textfield we have to create new FocusRequester

Answer (score 7):

With Compose in this instance you need to create a set of references to each focusable text field on your screen as below (textField1, textField2) and get a reference to the keyboardController.

Then you can add a type of action to your keyboard options signalling how the action button should look when the keyboard is displayed.

In the keyboardActions parameter, you can call a function on the specified IME action - in this case i've stated I want textField2 to take focus when the keyboard action button is pressed. You assign the references in the Modifier.focusRequester parameter in the TextField.

Lastly, to make your first TextField take focus when the screen appears, you call a DisposableEffect function where you specify you would like textField1 to take focus when the screen is first displayed.

```
val (textField1, textField2) = remember { FocusRequester.createRefs() }
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

TextField(
    modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(textField1),
    keyboardOptions  = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Next),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions( onNext = {textField2.requestFocus()}
   ),
)


 TextField(
    modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(textField2),
    keyboardOptions  = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions( onDone = { 
    keyboardController?.hide()}
   ),
)

DisposableEffect(Unit) {
    textField1.requestFocus()
    onDispose { }
}
```

Comment: This seems like the best approach, works with fields hidden behind a keyboard as well and gives control on where the focus should move to.

Answer (score 1):

For updated jetpack compose library, you can also use `LocalFocusManager` directly to move focus to the next `TextField` in your UI. Do the following to transfer focus from one TextField to another.

Note: I have used [BasicTextField2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.7.0-alpha03) in this example:

```
val localFocusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

BasicTextField2(
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
        imeAction = ImeAction.Next
    ),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
        onNext = { localFocusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Next) }
    )
 )
```

This automatically moves focus from your existing `TextField` to the next `TextField` in your declarative UI.

Also, when using `ImeAction.Done` you don't need to manually hide soft-keyboard in `keyboardActions`. It will do it automatically.